# Leaflet Tooltip collision plugin

Tags: javascript, dictionary, plugins, leaflet

I am looking for the best plugins to use to handle Leaflet tooltip/marker collisions for me. I've already looked into two, including

https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision

However, in my use case it's been found to have bugs and issues with my map and judging by the fact it's last update was nearly 7 years ago, I doubt that there's anything that can be done without modifying the codebase of the entire plugin.

I've also taken a look at

https://github.com/yakitoritabetai/Leaflet.LabelTextCollision/

However, there's no customization on this one and it's also very old which are both problems for me.

**Due to the vision I have in mind of my map, I can't use ClusterGroups because I want the points to show, just with labels that don't collide into each other.
**
Any recommendations? Thank you!

**Already tried:
**https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision
https://github.com/yakitoritabetai/Leaflet.LabelTextCollision/